# Lightdm greeter: Not running inside a display manager, XDG_SEAT_PATH not defined

Tags: xfce, screen-lock, lightdm

I am trying to use lightdm-webkit2-greeter under xfce. When I run `dm-tool lock`, I get `Not running inside a display manager, XDG_SEAT_PATH not defined`. When I run `dm-tool list-seats`, I get `Unable to contact display manager`. Is it possible to use lightdm-greeter in xfce?

`uname -a`:

```
Linux Hermes 4.6.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jun 24 21:19:13 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`dm-tool -v`:

```
lightdm 1.18.2
```